# Cant open Camera Servoce Android

Tags: android, camera

i stuck here with a Problem. Trying to build a torch app. Works fine, but when i switch fragment or go to homescreen and come back the flash light wont work. Error is failed to connect to camera service.

I think the Problem is, that I create a new Camera instance then, and the new cant connect to the camera anymore. But how should i solve it?

```
public class FlashCameraManager {

private boolean isFlashOn;
private Camera camera;
public Camera.Parameters params;


// getting camera parameters
public void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            camera = null;
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }   else {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

public void FlashOnOff()
{
    //Flash Aktivieren oder deaktivieren
    if (isFlashOn)
    {
        //Turn Flash off

        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();

        isFlashOn = false;
        Log.d("FlashCameraManager", "Turning Flash off");
    }
    else
    {
        // Turn Flash on
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();

        isFlashOn = true;
        Log.d("FlashCameraManager", "Turning Flash on");

    }
}

public boolean isFlashActive()
{
    //Prüfen ob Flash an oder aus ist
    return isFlashOn;
}}
```

This is from the MainActivity

```
        final ImageButton flash = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.none_flash);
    if(camera == null) {
        camera = new FlashCameraManager();
    }
    camera.getCamera();

    flash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Content
        if (camera.isFlashActive())
        {
            //Turn Flash off
            camera.FlashOnOff();
            Log.d("NoneFragment", "Turning Flash off");
            flash.setActivated(false);
        }
        else
        {
            //Turn Flash on
            camera.FlashOnOff();
            Log.d("NoneFragment", "Turning Flash on");
            flash.setActivated(true);
        }

    }} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you are done with the camera (i.e. before exiting the application or launching another activity) make sure that you release the camera resources by calling the method `release()`, which, per the API Guide, "Disconnects and releases the Camera object resources". The API guide also provides some valueable insight into properly utilizing the class and performing simple operations, such as tasking a picture. The API Guide may be found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

You might also want to consider taking a glance at the new camera API (android.hardware.camera2), as the current API that you are using is deprecated as of API level 21. The guide for the new API is found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. camera.release() was the Key. Put it in onPause() in my Fragment, so the camera automatically stops.

Comment: Another Questions: To Which API Level is camera2 runnable. Only 21 or am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct, android.hardware.camera2 is only available for API Level 21 and above, so it might not be the best choice if you are looking to support older devices; just wanted to make you aware that the API you are currently using is deprecated and might not be the best choice for future development.